# Laravel, Vue, Inertia, Vite using Teleport as a pop-up modal, dynamically called?

Tags: vuejs3, vite, inertiajs, laravel-10, php-8.2

By reading the title you can understand my stack, and problem, but let's explain it in detail.

I have a pop-up modal CheckOutModalPaper (which is basically a Teleport component.) that i'm using in my component Pricing.vue. The modal is prompt open when clicking a button that fires a method (for simplicity the method is called openModal()), which turns  the isOpen value from false to true, and with that poping the modal in the center of the screen.

```
Pricing.vue

<script setup>
import CheckoutModalPaper from '@/Components/CheckoutModalPaper.vue';

let isOpen = ref(false);

function openModal() {
    isOpen.value = true
}
</script>

<template>

    //somewhere in the middle
    <button @click="openModal()" >
        Open Modal
    </button>

    // At the bottom of the template
    <CheckoutModalPaper :show="isOpen" @close="isOpen = false">
        <div ref="checkoutContainer" id="paper-checkout-container" width="380px"></div>
        <div class="my-6 flex justify-center">
            <SecondaryButton @click="isOpen = false"> Close </SecondaryButton>
        </div>
    </CheckoutModalPaper>
</template>
```

My problem with this is that this modal is loaded every time even though the button is not clicked, and it can effect my pages load speed because of it...

Is there a way for this modal to be dynamically imported when clicking the button?

I have tried using

```
const CheckoutModalPaper = () => import('@/components/CheckoutModalPaper.vue');
```

but stumble upon this error in my console when clicking the button:

```
runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parentNode')
    at parentNode (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:33:30)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5825:11)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178:19)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5862:51)
    at updateComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5689:18)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5624:7)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5088:11)
    at patchBlockChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5475:7)
    at patchElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5367:7)
    at processElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5215:7)
```

I even tried calling importing the modal asynchronously inside the method openModal(), like so:

```
function openModal() {
    const CheckoutModalPaper = await import('@/Components/CheckoutModalPaper.vue');
    isOpen.value = true
}
```

but get the same error as above.

Looking forward to hear if there are any solution to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isnt really any need for a teleport approach, also keep in mind one shouldnt teleport outside the vue app itself iirc. You can define an async component like this

```
const UiComponent = (() => {
    return defineAsyncComponent(
        () => import("../../Components/CheckoutModalPaper.vue")
    );
```

Please note that you can use import aliases here like `@`

Comment: @disservin teleport makes things easy for making the div appear and disappear. Mind sharing your way of making a pop-up in vue?

Comment: you should use a html dialog element and put a ref on that ref="modal", you can define some actions like this on some buttons inside
```
const open = () => {
    modal.value?.showModal();
};

const close = () => {
    modal.value?.close();
};
```
And just apply some of the common css styles to the dialog like position fixed

Comment: @disservin ahh i see so good old css positioning. I honestly thought someone would comment a more modern way...